# Can we create static google maps with directions

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I would like to ask whether we can create static google maps with directions and send email with that image in the body of the mail along with the direction steps. Thank you.

More information: this is to be coded in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Substitute `origin` and `destination` values with your desired values, render

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps API v3 Directions Example</title> 
   <script type="text/javascript" 
           src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=de"></script>
</head> 
<body style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px;"> 
   <div style="width: 600px;">
     <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; float: left;"></div> 
     <div id="panel" style="width: 400px; float: left;"></div> 
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

     var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom:7,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });

     directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
     directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

     var request = {
       origin: 'Im Soll 43d, Hamburg', 
       destination: 'Albada 13, Cala Llombards, Mallorca',
       travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
     };

     directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
         directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
       }
     });
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

in the background, make PDF from rendered canvas, mail PDF.